# Populate IDML with XML without InDesign using sdk

Tags: sdk, adobe, idml

In my organization we are taking XML as input and trying populate *.idml file with it using adobe sdk and java. Is it possible to make working for any custom *.idml file? If yes what is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

idml files are just zip files that contain a number of XML files. You manipulate those XML files yourself or you can use libraries such as IDMLlib (http://idmllib.com/) to do some of the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 1):

IDML represents a very large number of settings and parameters, and even using a library such as IDMLLib, as SnB suggests, creating default values for all of these can be time consuming.

The best approach is to create a shell template with all the basic settings that you want by exporting a blank document from InDesign, and then inject your custom content into this in the form of spreads or stories or whatever else you need to create. A more advanced version of this technique might use a template for each different part of an IDML file (spreads, stories, textframes, etc) and populate, then assemble these to produce a finished document.